# How to configure Loki to accept requests with subpath?

Tags: grafana-loki

I want to talk my Loki instance with an address in the following format:

http://my.domain.com/monitoring/loki/

But I cannot find the correct place to configure it.

I assumed that Loki is based on Prometheus and that I could use flags like `--web.external-url`. But it seems that is not the case, as I have checked all available flags with `docker run grafana/loki --help`.

Am I missing something or do I have to add a reverse proxy between Loki and the rest of the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Use Nginx.

Even though Loki is based on Prometheus, it is currently not possible to make Loki listen at a subpath.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Use Nginx"? Did you manage to run your Loki service behind a reverse proxy at the http://my.domain.com/monitoring/loki/ path?

Comment: Yes that's how I do it / did it (I don't use Loki in production)

Comment: OK, this gives me hopes that it's possible :) Thank you

Comment: Do you remember how you managed that? What else is needed except from the loki configs to be:
```
server:
  http_listen_address: localhost
  http_listen_port: 3100
```

and the Nginx vhost to include:
```
location /loki/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3100/;
}
```
?

Comment: I think it was something along those lines, but I can't remember it off the top my head. Maybe I will find the time in the next few days to play around with it. Maybe something ahs changed in the meantime? <https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/1668>

Comment: Actually, that was all that was needed. The loki service is running properly, and I could see the metrics on my browser when going to /loki/metrics. However, I get a 404 (by Loki, not by Nginx) when I go to /loki. Since the service is up, this is an acceptable solution for now. I could not find any "external url" settings for Loki, similar to Prometheus, like you said.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone need it and come to this post, you have the possibility to use `-server.path-prefix=/loki` for that case.

All the api path will be served by this path.